# why In get method i am getting empty fields when posting request in react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, reactjs

I am posting the data from response API, fields like `connectionname`, `sid` and so on when I am checking in the get request I am not getting the data in the fields it is showing empty fields. Can anyone help me in this I am struck in this from couple of days.

```
render() {

     return (
     <div className="body_scroll"> 
     <section>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <h3 className="row_title">Add New Data Connection</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 ">
            <div className="top_row_right text-right">
            <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" type= "submit">Save</button>
              <button className="btn btn-primary"> Close</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section className="content_block">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <div className="connection_tab_block">
              <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                <li className="active"><a href="#con_setting" data-toggle="tab"> Connection Setting</a></li>

              </ul>
              <div id="connectionTabContent" className="tab-content">
                <div className="tab-pane fade active in" id="con_setting">
                  <div className="row clearfix">


                   <form onSubmit={this.submit} >

                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor className="col-md-4 control-label">Data Connection Name</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">


                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id placeholder="Data Connection Name" type="text"   valChange={this.dataConnectionNameChange} val={this.state.dataConnectionName}/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor className="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id placeholder="Description" type="text" 

                           valChange={this.descriptionChange} val={this.state.description} />
                    </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix">
                        <label htmlFor=" " className="col-md-4 control-label">Type</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <select className="form-control box_ip" ><option> Oracle </option></select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix">
                        <label htmlFor="inputEmail" className="col-md-4 control-label">Connection Method</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <select className="form-control box_ip">
                          <option> JDBC </option>
                          <option> ODBC </option>

                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor=" " className="col-md-4 control-label">Database Host</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id=" " placeholder="Database Host" type="text" 

                          valChange={this.databaseHostChange} val={this.state.databaseHost} />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor=" " className="col-md-4 control-label">Database Port</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id=" " placeholder="Database Port" type="text" 

                          valChange={this.databasePortChange} val={this.state.databasePort} />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor=" " className="col-md-4 control-label">SID</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id=" " placeholder="SID" type="text" 

                           valChange={this.dataConnectionSidChange} val={this.state.dataConnectionSid} />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor=" " className="col-md-4 control-label"> Driver</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id=" " placeholder=" Driver" type="text" 


                          valChange={this.jdbcDriverChange} val={this.state.jdbcDriver}  />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor=" " className="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id=" " placeholder="Username" type="text" 


                          valChange={this.dataConnectionUsernameChange} val={this.state.dataConnectionUsername} />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                      <div className="form-group clearfix is-empty">
                        <label htmlFor=" " className="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>                        
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                          <input className="form-control box_ip" id=" " placeholder="Password" type="text" 


                          valChange={this.dataConnectionPasswordChange} val={this.state.dataConnectionPassword} />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    </form>                            
                  </div>  
                </div>

              </div> 
            </div>           
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>   
    </section>


  </div>


    );
}
```

Comment: componentDidMount() {
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
         },
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/UIServices/rest/dataService/postDataConnection?userName=SIVASO',
        data: JSON.stringify({
        dataConnectionName: this.state.dataConnectionName,
        dataConnectionType: this.state.dataConnectionType,
        databaseHost: this.state.databaseHost
        
     })
      
  }

Comment: handleSubmit(e){
    var self
      
      e.preventDefault();
      self = this

      console.log(this.state);

      var data = {
        dataConnectionName: this.state.dataConnectionName,
        dataConnectionType: this.state.dataConnectionType
        
      }
      }

Comment: you can edit your question. instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: showing error when adding in code

Comment: if you understand can you give solution i a struck from 2 days

Comment: console.log(this.state); what is output of this line?

Comment: i think you are submitting immediately after loading component that time values will be empty only. move your ajax code to handleSubmit(e){}.

Comment: console.log(this.state); this also not printing any output

Comment: why you are submitting form on componentDidMount() that time values will be empty right? on click of submit button only you should submit. i suggest you to check flow of your code

Comment: when i move ajax code in handleSubmit response itself not displaying anything i tried with that. when i loaded ajax in componentdidmount response is geting success but the values are not inserting in the fields storing empty values

Comment: when you want to submit form? where is your submit() function code?. in  <form onSubmit={this.submit}> you mentioned this.submit()?

Comment: handleSubmit(e){
    var self
      e.preventDefault();
      self = this
      console.log(this.state);
      var data = {
        dataConnectionName: this.state.dataConnectionName
      
      }
      }

Comment: hi dinesh can you send your email so that i can send you the entire code so that you can able to resolve please. this i need to resolve immediatly

Comment: I know because of small mistake. i am facing this  from couple of days back

Comment: yes you can thank you

Comment: @mantenasiva, Do you have a git repository to share your code? It will be a lot of help.

Comment: yes i am having

Comment: sivasai081 is my username and kasei-webui is the repository you can check the connsetting component and dataconnection component.

Comment: From connsetting component i am posting the data and to the dataconnection i need to populate the post request from connsetting  component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on submit you are calling `this.submit` function but in your code you declared as `handleSubmit()`. change the name of submit function from `handleSubmit` to submit

```js
handleSubmit(e){
    var self e.preventDefault();
    self = this console.log(this.state); 
    var data = { dataConnectionName:this.state.dataConnectionName, dataConnectionType: this.state.dataConnectionType };
} 
// use this function 

submit(e){
    var self e.preventDefault();
    self = this console.log(this.state); 
    var data = { dataConnectionName:this.state.dataConnectionName, dataConnectionType: this.state.dataConnectionType };

}
```